# BeagleBone Black: Getting an image from eMMC back to the SD Card

Tags: beagleboneblack, beagleboard

The steps I take to install a BeagleBone Black are to take an sd card I had previously dd'd an image of wheezy into, then insert it into the BeagleBone Black, hold down a button while booting, and the image gets burned onto the BeagleBone Black's eMMC.

I then run through a setup procedure and was about to start writing a script to automate this except that it still feels inefficient.

I am wondering if there is a way I can skip this altogether by simply cloning an already set up beaglebone black to the SD card so that I can simply flash a new beaglebone black and it is ready to go.  Searches on Google really only show the other way around (SD->eMMC) and not eMMC->SD.

Answer (score 0):

On elinux.org you can find a way how to create such an image from eMMC:

http://elinux.org/BeagleBone_Black_Extracting_eMMC_contents

Comment: Once that SD card is made, I am unable to flash it back to the eMMC.  I am trying to make an install card.